# Triple Triad - Plus rule strange behaviour

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I’ve just played a game of Triple Triad with the Plus rule. I understand how the rule works, but a move I’ve just made doesn’t make sense to me. See the screenshot below. I just played the Moogle card and the card to the left and below was a red card. I expected both cards to flip but as you can see only the card on the left flipped. Both side of the cards add up to the same value. Can anyone explain why they didn’t both flip?
[image: screenshot]

Another example, but this time cards flipped when I didn’t expect them to. See the screenshot below. The top left and top right cards were both blue. Red plays the top middle card and that flips both the top left and top right card even though 9+1 doesn’t equal 6+6. How come the cards have flipped?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't play a lot of Triple Triad, but these screenshots imply that another rule in play for each screenshot:

- Ascension Beastman is in play for the first screenshot; the cards marked with +5 have 5 added to each of their values (max value 10)... meaning that the plus value on the left of the Moogle card is 17 while the plus value on the bottom of the Moogle card is 18.  You still took the Frixio card because of the normal rules.
- Descension Primal and Descension Beastman are both in play for the second screenshot; while the Primal cards are marked as -3 (min value 1) in the screenshot, the screenshot isn't actually from when the play happened... they were likely marked -2 when the Good King Moggle Mog XII card was actually played, which would make the left and right sides both 10.

Comment: The vital rule I was missing is that the cards can only have a max of 10 and minimum of 1. Thank you! Unless I missed it, I don’t think the in-game help explains this. It is confirmed here though https://eu.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/playguide/contentsguide/goldsaucer/tripletriad/.